# Receiving 'Request String' in Python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, port

I'm building a game-server in Python. The functionality is pretty well-defined. The server will listen on the port 6000 and a remote client will send a request. Then the server will establish a connection to the client's port 7000. From then on, the client will keep sending 'requests' (basically, strings such as `"UP#", "DOWN#", "SHOOT#"` etc.) to server's port 6000.

This is the problem. I have made a 'server' who listens on the port 6000. This means I cannot bind a client to the same port. Is there a way that I can get the data string of an incoming request in a server? So far, I only have this.

What am I doing wrong here? Any workarounds for this issue? In short, can I read the incoming request string from a client in the server code?

Thanks in advance.

```
def receive_data(self):
    errorOccured = False
    connection = None
    try:
        listener = socket.socket()  # Create a socket object.
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 6000               # The port that the server keeps listening to.
        listener.bind(('', port))
        # Start listening
        listener.listen(5)
        statement = ("I:P0:7,6;8,1;0,4;3,8;3,2;1,6:5,4;9,3;8,7;2,6;1,4;2,7;6,1;6,3:2,1;8,3;5,8;9,8;7,2;0,3;9,4;4,8;7,1;6,8#\n","S:P0;0,0;0#","G:P0;0,0;0;0;100;0;0:4,3,0;5,4,0;3,8,0;2,7,0;6,1,0;5,8,0;1,4,0;1,6,0#",                       "C:0,5:51224:824#","G:P0;0,0;0;0;100;0;0:4,3,0;5,4,0;3,8,0;2,7,0;6,1,0;5,8,0;1,4,0;1,6,0#","G:P0;0,1;2;0;100;0;0:4,3,0;5,4,0;3,8,0;2,7,0;6,1,0;5,8,0;1,4,0;1,6,0#")
        # This is just game specific test data
        while True:
            c, sockadd = listener.accept()    # Establish connection with client.
            print 'incoming connection, established with ', sockadd

            i = 0 # Just a counter.
            while i<len(statement):
                try:
                    self.write_data(statement[i], sockadd[0])
                    time.sleep(1) # The game sends updates every second to the clients
                    i = i + 1
                    #print listener.recv(1024) -- this line doesn't work. gives an error
                except:
                    print "Error binding client"
            c.close() # Close the connection
        return
    except:
        print "Error Occurred"
```

Comment: UPDATE: I found that I can use SocketServer to implement a 'RequestHandler'. I think it could help.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/18/code-sample-socket-client-thread-in-python/ for a pretty decent socket server / client implementation

Comment: This is a strange way of game networking. Anyone behind NAT or a firewall wouldn't be able to play without port forwarding... Why would the server open a socket to the client?

Comment: @korylprince - This game is supposed to be given to the junior computer science and engineering students of our university. It has these specific requirements that they are supposed to get to know how it works inside out and should be open and simple. The idea is not to create a perfect game server but to provide a sort of a learning experience to the students in aspects of networking, AI and UI design.

Comment: @damith219 yes, but sockets are bidirectional. Why not show them that even though the client connects to the server that the server can communicate back on that one socket.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer it because I got some help and figured it out.

The most basic thing I can do is to use the client connection which is `c` for this purpose. In here, instead of the commented line `data=listener.recv(1024)` I should have used `data= c.recv(1024)`. Now it works.

Another way is to use SocketServers with a StreamingRequestHandler. While this is ideal for usage of typical servers, if a lot of objects are involved it could reduce the flexibility.